# Jquery tabs disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have this code in my jquery :

```
(function(a) {
    a.fn.extend({tabify: function(e) {
            function c(b) {
                hash = a(b).find("a").attr("href");
                return hash = hash.substring(0, hash.length - 4)
            }
            function f(b) {
                a(b).addClass("active");
                a(c(b)).show();
                a(b).siblings("li").each(function() {
                    a(this).removeClass("active");
                    a(c(this)).hide()
                })
            }
            return this.each(function() {
                function b() {
                    location.hash && a(d).find("a[href=" + location.hash + "]").length > 0 && f(a(d).find("a[href=" + location.hash + "]").parent())
                }
                var d = this, g = {ul: a(d)};
                a(this).find("li a").each(function() {
                    a(this).attr("href", a(this).attr("href") + "-tab")
                });
                location.hash && b();
                setInterval(b, 100);
                a(this).find("li").each(function() {
                    a(this).hasClass("active") ? a(c(this)).show() : a(c(this)).hide()
                });
                e && e(g)
            })
        }})
})(jQuery);
```

and this is HTML and script of the tabs

$("#menu").tabify({
        disabled: true
    });

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#jquery">jQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#prototype">Prototype</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ext">Ext</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="jquery">
   jQuery is a cross-browser…
  </div>
  <div id="prototype">
   The Prototype JavaScript…
  </div>
  <div id="ext">
   Ext (X-t) is a JavaScript…
  </div>
```

and I want to add the tabs have a disable in my plugins.Could someone please show me the correct way to do it?

Comment: what do you want to do while disabling it

Comment: also why can't you use http://jqueryui.com/tabs